# merging a list with a list of lists into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pygame

I want to be able to refer to a list from a dictionary by using objects from another list. The first list is a list of rectangle objects, and the second list is a list of smaller rect objects divided from the first list.

This is what I tried:

```
def merge(self, parent_list, child_list):
    tile_dict = dict(zip(parent_list, child_list))
    return tile_dict
```

However I get the error "Unhashable type: pygame.Rect". Is it not possible to use a dict for this purpose? If so, what would be the appropriate list comprehension to accomplish something similiar to what was originally intended?

Comment: Can you tell us more about `rect` objects?  Are they mutable?  If not, you could probably make them hashible by providing some form of `__hash__` method.

Comment: they are pygame rectangle objects with position, width and height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define your own class derived from pygame.Rect:

```
class HashableRect(pygame.Rect):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(self))
```

works fine:

```
 >>> r = HashableRect(1,2,3,4)
 >>> {r: 'something'}
 {<rect(1, 2, 3, 4)>: 'something'}
```

The problem with this: `pygame.Rect` is a mutable type. You can change the values it contains, and therefore the hash would change, which shouldn't happen.

If you only care for object identities, you could return `id(self)` as the hash value.

Or you could also just convert it to a tuple (it's basically isn't much more then a 4-tuple anyway) and use that as key in the dict and when doing lookups:

```
def merge(self, parent_list, child_list):
    tile_dict = dict(zip(map(tuple, parent_list), child_list))
    return tile_dict

merged = merge(prarent_list, child_list)
...
child = merged[tuple(parent)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Keys of dictionarys have to be hashable, that means they have to have a `__hash__` method which yields the same output if the objects have the same 'value' and should never change in the lifetime of an object.
You have to provide that hash method if applicable, or you simulate a dict by keeping a list of both lists and lookup the child per index of the parent. This works, but would be O(n) lookup cost.